# Lost Drupal node content

Tags: drupal

A Drupal site a friend has on my server (WHM/CPanel) show his menu navigation on the left but the links go to the Welcome to your new site screen.
I think he must have tried to upgrade Drupal.  How to I resync the navigation so /node/15 points to his actual content?

EDIT
MySQL was updated yesterday and then my friend called today to say his Drupal site was broken.  I was away from my computer so I asked my brother in law to help since he new Drupal better than I.  I'm not sure exactly everything the two of them did but it looks like they upgraded to a newer Drupal or tried to upgrade because when you browse to his site, it shows the standard

```
 Welcome to your new Drupal website!
 Please follow these steps to set up and start using your website:
```

But all his menu navigation (I guess they are nodes?) are displayed but when you click any one of those links, it just goes to the same default `Welcome to your Drupal site'

Comment: This is suited for drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can you tell us more information about the problem? Actually it is hard to get the problem now.

Comment: how do I migrate it [my question] over? Thanks.

Comment: what is the meaning of "migrate" actually here? :) was the drupal installation in another server (and fine working) and now the problem happens when you put it to your server?

Comment: sorry, migrate the question to drupal.stackexchange.com as suggested by Programming Enthusiast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem.  I noticed the `node_revisions` table in the database had all the content entries.  But there were no corresponding entries in the `node` table.  Through the main site I added some content and noticed the entries made in both those tables.  I made note of the format. I then inserted records accordingly into the `nodes` table and whola all content appeared when I clicked the menu links.

I did a bulk SQL load using phpMyAadmin

```
INSERT INTO `node` (`nid`, `vid`, `type`, `title`, `uid`, `status`, `created`, `changed`, `comment`, `promote`, `moderate`, `sticky`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'page', 'zzxxzz', 1, 1, 1329017099, 1329017449, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(2, 2, 'page', 'zzxxzz', 1, 1, 1329017099, 1329017449, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(3, 3, 'page', 'zzxxzz', 1, 1, 1329017099, 1329017449, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(4, 4, 'page', 'zzxxzz', 1, 1, 1329017099, 1329017449, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(5, 5, 'page', 'zzxxzz', 1, 1, 1329017099, 1329017449, 0, 0, 0, 0),
```

etc... up to the total number of nodes listed in the `node_revision` table

I had 141 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Node revision tables have all the write a script to import data to node table.